# Create a generic Interceptor for mapping to DTO

Tags: nestjs

I am writing in **nestjs**

In the controller, I am using **@UseInterceptors** on a function.

I want to create an Interceptor that maps the response data to DTO (I am mapping entity to DTO)
Is there a way to create it to map the data to DTO class but in a way that the DTO class will be passed to it and not be hard coded in the interceptor, I want to use it in several modules that return different DTO's and I don't want to write several interceptors.

Can you give me an example?